# Python: can't manage to generalize function with a string input. For cycle doesn't iterate

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, elementtree, function

I have a xml tree with some content and I want to count how many tree elements have a specific keyword. Here's the xml structure

```
<tree>
    <tw>
        <con>Bla bla bla</con>
    </tw>
    <tw>
        <con>Bla bla bla bla bla</con>
    </tw>
    ...
</tree>
```

And here's the function I wrote. I'm using python 2.7.

```
def conta_una(tree, kw1):
    conta=[]
    for i, tw in enumerate(tree.findall('tw')):
        for con in tw.findall('con'):
            if con.text and kw1 in con.text:
                conta.append(tw.getchildren())
    print(len(conta))
```

Then i import the function in python, i define the two variables and call the function

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tr1 = ElementTree().parse('/path/file.xml')
keyword = "word"
conta_una(tr1, keyword)
```

No matter what keyword i put in the variable `keyword` I always get 1 as result. But if I write the function explicitly like this

```
tree = ElementTree().parse('/path/file.xml')
conta=[]
for i, tw in enumerate(tree.findall('tw')):
    for con in tw.findall('con'):
        if con.text and "word" in con.text:
            conta.append(tw.getchildren())
print(len(conta))
```

I get the right result. I'm sure I'm doing a very stupid mistake in the function definition, but I can't understand what, even looking at the manual.

Comment: Have you tried any print statements in the function? .

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your *example* file and ```bla``` as a keyword.

Comment: If I print the list `conta` I can see it has just one element, so that's the reason why it gives me 1 as a result. I thought the string input was the problem, but is not: the function `conta_una` does't iterate the for cycle. But why? I can't understand my mistake. (I edited the question title)

Comment: Probably not the problem, but why are you using `enumerate`, and why a list instead of just a counter? Also, can not reproduce.

Comment: tobias_k, I'm a beginner and the only way I could think to retrieve the number of children of the tree was to make a list containing all the children and then print len of the list. surely not the more efficient way to do the task, but it works (when I put the variables manually). and I use enumerate because I shamelessly copied the first part of the function from nltk book, I just thought it was the best way to do it and I didn't think to change it. any suggestions are well accepted :P